# is PHPDocX community version able to convert docx or doc to html with formatting

Tags: php, codeigniter, converters, phpdocx

my question is simple.

I would like to know that is `PHPDocX` community version able to convert `docx` or `doc` file to

`HTML` version with formatting?

i have not yet tried it.. but would like to know if it is possible so that i can look out for others solutions..and save some time..

i am using codeigniter.. if someone has a working code of the same requirement.. please at least suggest me how i can too achieve this..

thanks in advance..

Comment: PHPDocx's purpose is the opposite way, generating DOC/DOCX from PHP/HTML. Nevertheless, I've never considered the other way.

Answer (score 1):

[transformDocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/advanced-conversion-plugin/convert-Word-docx-into-pdf-with-PHP) might do what you want, but requires Pro+ or Corp version.